# Finding out whether an EPSG code is geographic or projected in Python

Tags: python, epsg

Can one tell that from the number of digits or a similar rule?

Comment: The WKT of geographic coordinate systems contains GEOGCRS https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/4326. Compare with PROJCRS in https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/3857.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [PyCRS](https://github.com/karimbahgat/PyCRS) library.

```
import pycrs

crs3857 = pycrs.parse.from_epsg_code(3857)
print("EPSG:3857 is " + crs3857.cs_type)

crs4326 = pycrs.parse.from_epsg_code(4326)
print("EPSG:4326 is " + crs4326.cs_type)
```

Output:

```
EPSG:3857 is Projected
EPSG:4326 is Geographic
```

You can also use `isinstance` method of Python with PyCRS:

```
isinstance(crs3857, pycrs.ProjCS)
# True

isinstance(crs4326, pycrs.GeogCS)
# True
```

Comment: Worked fine for me thanks!. But the 'pycrs.parse.from_epsg_code' part takes soo long for me (at least 2 minutes). Is there a faster solution?

Comment: @David Maybe it is related to your internet connection or [epsg.io](https://epsg.io). When using EPSG code, the package uses [epsg.io](https://epsg.io).

Answer (score 4):

The best way, I guess, is to use `pyproj` itself.

```py
from pyproj import CRS

crs3857 = CRS(3857) # Web Mercator
crs4326 = CRS(4326) # WGS84

crs3857.is_projected  # True
crs3857.is_geographic # False

crs4326.is_projected  # False
crs4326.is_geographic # True
```